# Does Craft automatically sanitize user input?

Tags: craft3, filter, controller

Can I rely on Craft to clean user input, is safe to save the following data like in the below example function, if not, what is the Craft best practice for cleaning(making it safe) user input?

```
public function actionCustomSaveUser(){

    $user = new User();
    $user->newPassword = $_POST['password'];
    $user->username = $_POST['username'];
    // and more $_POST ...

    Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($user, false);
    // etc...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would access the post using this format

`Craft::$app->getRequest()->post('username')`

Craft then extends the YII 2 request object. Does it sanitise input, not really, but models can set validation rules like this

https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/how-does-yii-handle-data-sanitization/83006

Comment: Perfect, thank you.